# Exited with exitcode=217

Tags: pascal, freepascal

can anyone help me with the following program? There is no compile message, but during the runtime, an error is occured, and the message is, exited with exitcode=217.
What seems to be the problem?

The text that the program reads is like this

> 3 2
>
> 1 2
>
> 1 3
>
> 1 2

Where 3 is n for instance, so the procedure the program must be done 3 times, so as all the nums., will be read.

```
Program sth;
Uses
SysUtils;
Var
m:Integer;
LowArr:Integer;
HighArr:Integer;
n,d:String;
f:Text;
TheArray,j:array of integer;
a:array of char;
c:array of string[1];
v:String[1];
i:Integer;

Procedure thenum ;
Begin
repeat
Read (f,a[i]);
Write(a[i]);
until (a[i]=' ');
End;

Procedure sth ;
begin
while not seekEoln and eof(f) do
begin
read(f,j[i]);
Write(j[i]);
end;
End;


procedure space;
begin
Read(f,c[i]);
Write(c[i]);
end;


Procedure theprogram;
begin
thenum;
space;
sth;
end;

begin
Assign(f,'textfile.txt');
Reset(f);
repeat
Read (f,n);
Write(n);
until (n=' ');

Read(f,v);
Write(v);
while not seekEoln and eof(f) do
begin
read(f,d);
Write(d);
end;
StrToIntDef(n,m);
setlength(thearray,m);
LowArr:=Low(Thearray);
HighArr:=High(TheArray);
for i:= LowArr to HighArr do
theprogram;
if eof(f) then;
Close(f);
Readln;
End.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get exitcode 217 if the file named `textfile.txt` does not exist in the same directory as the executable.

```
read(f,n);
```

will read the file into `n`, up to the end-of-line. Then it will get stuck. You nedd a `readLN` to read the newline.

Similarly, `write(n);` will write `n` to the console, but there will be no newline; you need `writeln(n);` to add a newline.

It's not clear quite exactly what your file-structure is. Spaces are hard to see. If you use `readln(f,n);` then `n` will contain the content of the line read - and if you want to detect an empty line, then you need `until n='';`, with no space between the quotes.

Since you don't supply `seekEoLN` with a parameter, it works on the keyboard, not the file. You need `seekEoln(f)` to find the end-of-line in the file.

Keep plugging away - you'll get there. I'd suggest you remove your `seekEoln`s and take great care over whether you want to read an entire line (readln) or just a character (read)

Comment: Thank you very much, your help was really valuable.